# emacs lsp-mode python how to disable certain warnings

Tags: python, warning, lsp-mode

lsp-mode complies to PEP8 style guide I guess, but how can I disable certain warnings, e.g. about missing docstrings etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
(setq lsp-pyls-plugins-pycodestyle-enabled nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple answer, since `python-lsp-server` aggregate warnings from different sources. Mainly `pycodestyle`/`flake8` and `pycodestyle`.

The easiest will be to add a `setup.cfg` file which list the error you want to ignore. For example, for missing docs, simply add:

```
[pydocstyle]
ignore = D100,D101,D102,D107
```